# Bootstrap-4 Vertical Navbar Stuck Collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I'm just starting to get to grips with bootstrap.

I'm trying to create a vertical-navbar on the left of the page after the user has scrolled past the full-page 'intro' using bootstrap 4. The code below produces the navbar on the left side of the page, however there is a problem with it

- The navbar stays in a collapsed state, even after resizing the window small and large again

Why does the code cause the navbar to start closed?

Thanks, Jeff

```
<header id="home" class="jumbotron h-100vw w-100vw">
...
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Home">
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse-md flex-column" id="nav-content">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#about"></a>About Me</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#work">My Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#connect">Stay Connected</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <main class="col-md-10">
        REST OF MY CONTENT ON THE RIGHT
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to implement a collapse vertical navbar and I tried your code and it didn't wok. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `navbar-collapse-md` class. Change it to just `navbar-collapse`.

```
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="nav-content">
             <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#about"></a>About Me
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#work">My Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#connect">Stay Connected</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Get In Touch</a>
                    </li>
             </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However I still appear to have the same problem. Any other thoughts?

Comment: No, it should work. Which version of Bootstrap 4? `col-md-2` is very narrow to contain a horizontal navbar. Why would you expect it to become fixed position "After resizing it to a small enough state"?

Comment: I was using the flex-column to create a vertical navbar (which appears to work fine). As for the fixed position, that was a complight oversight on my part! Not really used to web-development. This is the latest version of bootstrap, the bootstrap 4.0.0 full release

Comment: The `flex-column` would go on the `navbar-nav` to make it vertical. This is how the [code you posted would look now](https://www.codeply.com/go/gI7pW9hIuu) ... w/o the `navbar-collapse-md`